# Transition of segment in Semantic doesn't work

Tags: semantic-ui

I wanted to make flip over effect after pushing the button ui hugh primary button, so that after pushing  the button the text will flip. Unfortunately it seems not to work. I have already tried with ui shape and the result is the same- nothing happens. Could somebody tell me what is wrong? Thank you very much!

```
<div class="logo">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/../../../node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css">
<script src="/../../../node_modules/semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>

    <div class="ui black inverted segment">
      <div class="ui inverted header">
  <h2>Some text
      </h2>
<div class="ui hugh primary button" id="flip">Start!</div>
</div>
  <script>
    $('#flip').click(function() {
      $('.ui.inverted.header').header('flip over');
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From Semantic-ui docs I found there is no `flip over` transition!

> An element can [flip](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/transition.html#/definition) into or out of view vertically or horizontally

I was able to do `horizontal flip` using your code after some modifications.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
          $('#flip').click(function() {
      $('.ui.black.inverted.segment').transition('horizontal flip');
    });
     });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js"></script>


    <div class="ui black inverted segment">
      <div class="ui inverted header">
  <h2>Some text
      </h2>
      

</div>

</div>
<div class="ui hugh primary button" id="flip">Start!</div>
```

Also I noticed the button element within the segment which I see an issue, in addition to links to resources within the HTML blocks!

Comment: Thank you @Abuabdellah, do you know why it doesn't work with angular? I will start a new question about it.

Comment: That needs to review your code, let's the answer to be there.